# How to grab parent data from a firebase database?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

Here is my database and I only want to grab the titles and put them into a list but when I call data snapshot I get every single piece of data in the database with this code:

```
 void readTitle()
  {
    DBRef.child('Movies').once().then((DataSnapshot datasnapshot){
      print('MOVIE TITLE SNAP SHOT');
      print(datasnapshot.value.toString());
    });
  }
```

[image]

If you cannot do this, then what are some work arounds? Can I parse the entire data snapshot somehow to get only the titles into a list? I am not 100% sure how to do that or how to make this work for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

```
  Future<List<String>> getMovies() async{
    DataSnapshot movies =  await DBRef.child("Movies").once();
    var moviesMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(movies.value);
    var moviesList = [];
    moviesMap.forEach((key, value){
      moviesList.add(key);
    });
    return moviesList //moviesList is a List of the movie names;
  }
```